# Count the number of occurences in an Excel data range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Data]

My problem is that I am trying to count the number of sub-categories of column A in column B in excel but not sure how. For example, I want to get the number 2 for category a (a1 & a2), number 5 for category b (b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 & b5) and number 1 for category c (c1).

Comment: have you tried anything? your sample dataset is very generic which makes your question too broad to answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to accomplish what you are looking to do:

**Make sure that there is a blank line above your first row of data (your first "a" and "a1" will need to start in row 2) to keep this simple and make this example work.

Once your data has been shifted per the above, enter this in cell C2 and copy it down as far as your data goes:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(B2,B$1:B1,0),"unique")<>"unique","","unique")
```

Then, to sum the number of distinct categories, enter the following wherever you like:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"a",C:C,"unique")
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"b",C:C,"unique")
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"c",C:C,"unique")
```

This can be expanded as needed.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a neat way of doing it :)